# Woocommerce: How to show Product Attribute name on title when in a category page and "filtering" products via '?pa_attribute=' on address bar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have a product attribute (for ex.: color) and I can show only products inside a Category that have that attribute by using, for ex., *?pa_color=red* in the address bar, so if I go '*[www.mysite.com/product-category/t-shirts/?pa_color=red*'](http://www.mysite.com/product-category/t-shirts/?pa_color=red*%27) I'll have only t-shirts that have the color red as an attribute. That works.
The problem is, when I do that "filtering", the page title (above the product listing) still says only *"T-Shirts"*, it does not specify that it's only showing Red T-shirts and it might confuse clients. What I need is for it to show something like *"T-shirts (Color:Red)"*.
I know I can use sidebar widgets to filter attributes and then the widget will show what is being filtered but in this specific case is a very minimal design without sidebar or any filtering, I need it to show in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'custom_woocommerce_page_title', 15, 1 );

function custom_woocommerce_page_title( $page_title ) {
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        $exists_attr = false;

        foreach ( $_GET as $index => $value ) {
            if ( substr( $index, 0, 3 ) === 'pa_' ) {
                $attr_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $index );

                if ( $attr_id === 0 ) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ( ! $exists_attr ) {
                    $exists_attr = true;

                    $page_title .= ' (';
                } else {
                    $page_title .= ', ';
                }

                $page_title .= wc_attribute_label( $index ) . ': ' . esc_html( $value );
            }
        }

        if ( $exists_attr ) {
            $page_title .= ')';
        }
    }

    return $page_title;
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!
I just changed the following line so i could get the attribute 'name' instead of the 'slug':
FROM: `$page_title .= wc_attribute_label( $index ) . ': ' . esc_html( $value );`
TO:
       `$term = get_term_by( 'slug', esc_html( $value ), $index );
       $page_title .= wc_attribute_label( $index ) . ': ' . $term->name;`

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This works but it is bad for seo issues.
Your "page" does not really exist and wont be indexed by google.
The real solution would be to create a real page like :
[www.mysite.com/product-category/t-shirts/red](http://www.mysite.com/product-category/t-shirts/red)

But this is a mix of category and attributes and i dont know how it can be achieved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).