# PHP Function that executes a JS - Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I have a JS function that I am trying to execute via my functions.php from within my child theme. This is my first time utilizing PHP so I apologize if my code is poor.

My goal is to try to change the page_title to what has been selected in a dropdown filter. After this is working I then plan to add the category_name to the end of the .innerHTML. This will only occur in the event that a drop down has been selected. In the event it hasn't been then just the category will display via how woocommerce handles it natively.

```
var machineEl = document.getElementsByClassName('woof_select_pa_machine').firstChild;
var machineValue = machineEl.value;
    
    machineEl.addEventListener('change', function dynamic_page_title() {

        if (machineValue != 'Product Machine') {
            
            document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-products-header__title').innerHTML = machineValue;
        }  
    });
```

This is the first script I try to execute in the function.php.

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'dynamic_page_title_js();',
     '</script>';
?>
```

Alternatively I was trying to use the following to accomplish the same thing but with the intention to limiting to only certain pages. Though not sure if I will need this in the end. I used this set of code per another thread I found.

```
<?php

add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dynamic_page_title_php');

function dynamic_page_title_php() {

    //$wp_query->get_queried_object()->cat_name;

    global $page_title;

    if( is_page() || is_single() )
    {
        switch($page_title->title_name ) // post_name is the post slug which is more consistent for matching to here
        {
            case 'shop':
                wp_enqueue_script('shop', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dynamic_page_title_js.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
                break;
           
        }
    } 
    
}

?>
```

Here is the html of the class I am trying to overwrite.

```
<h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title">Sample Page</h1>
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a ReferenceError: dynamic_page_title_js is not defined

Comment: PHP is running from server side and JS is on client site (browser), you can't call javascript function from PHP.

Comment: That is kind of what I was starting to think as well. What would be the best approach? place in footer?                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                          
function dynamic_page_title_php() {
echo '<script>
function dynamice_page_title_js() {
}
</script>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_php_function');

Comment: do you want change the title and url by dropdown selected right ? there 2 different approach, 1. pass all value you need from php to client and process it by js, if the data is small this the best approach. 2. pull data from server (php) with ajax and update your dom with js (API)

Comment: the data is quite small. It is the just the category and the value of the selected drop down. So approach 1 is probably the best option. The drop down is already passing the url as it directs to the correct page.

Comment: I was able to get this working by using JS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take this a different route and break the issue apart. I used a js function to update page_title on filter select. Then I used code provided in another thread ([Woocommerce: How to show Product Attribute name on title when in a category page and "filtering" products via '?pa_attribute=' on address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892957/woocommerce-how-to-show-product-attribute-name-on-title-when-in-a-category-page)) to handle the attribute portion from within my function.php file. The php function handles the page on load replacing shop with the attribute name, in this case the machine type. The js updates this attribute and adds the category on filter select.

There is still some work to be done on the functions.php to add the category name to the page_title when the user navigates to a category via the nav bar. I have posted a new question on how to resolve this last part ([Woocommerce: How to show Product Attribute name and Category name on title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65833871/woocommerce-how-to-show-product-attribute-name-and-category-name-on-title)) but by utilizing both these independently it is more or less accomplishing what I intended.

Also, the JS I am currently executing within the woof-woocommerece-product-filter plugin. It is written within the JS after Ajax is done section. But I do plan to move this in to its own file and call the function only from a organizational aspect.

PHP

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'custom_woocommerce_page_title', 15, 2 );

function custom_woocommerce_page_title( $page_title ) {
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        $exists_attr = false;

        foreach ( $_GET as $index => $value ) {
            if ( substr( $index, 0, 3 ) === 'pa_' ) {
                $attr_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $index );

                if ( $attr_id === 0 && $cat_id ) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ( ! $exists_attr /* && ! $exists_cat */) {
                    $exists_attr = true;

                    $page_title .= ' ';
                } else {
                    $page_title .= ' ';
                }

                $term = get_term_by( 'slug', esc_html( $value ), $index );
                $page_title =  $term->name;                     
                        
            }
        }

    }

    return $page_title;

}
```

JS

```
(function() {
  var machineEl = document.getElementsByClassName('woof_select woof_select_pa_machine')[0];
  var processEl = document.getElementsByClassName('woof_select woof_select_pa_processing')[0];
  var optionMachine = machineEl.querySelector("option[selected='selected']");
  var optionProcess = processEl.querySelector("option[selected='selected']");
  var machineValue = optionMachine.innerHTML;
  var processValue = optionProcess.innerHTML;
  var result = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-products-header__title page-title')[0];
  if (machineValue != 'Product Machine' && processValue != 'Product Processing') {
            result.innerHTML = machineValue + " " + processValue;            
  }
  else if (machineValue != 'Product Machine') {
            result.innerHTML = machineValue;            
  }
  else if (processValue != 'Product Processing') {
            result.innerHTML = processValue;            
  }       
})()
```

Once I have the category posting the to page_title I will update this answer.